# Unable to get data input in the jsp, from jsp to a form, using logic:iterate

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1, taglib

The main problem is that I use Struts 1.0.2. But I can't change it.
I have an issue using an attribute of an arraylist in my jsp. The display works fine but I don't get the data instanciated in the arraylist in my form. In debug mode I see that it never comes to the getter of my property. I've found 2 solutions in struts 1.0 but I can't make it works.

The arraylist in my ActionForm :

```
private ArrayList<AccountScreenBean> accountsScreen = new ArrayList<AccountScreenBean>();
```

The class declaration of the Account object in the Arraylist :

```
public class Account implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    private String bic;

    public String getBic() {
        return bic;
    }

    public void setBic(final String newBic) {
        bic = newBic;
    }
}
```

The call in my jsp :

```
<logic:iterate name="BankAccountsActionForm" property="accountsScreen" id="accScreen" indexId="index">
<html:text name="accScreen" property="<%="accountsScreen["+index+"].bic"%>" size="18" maxlength="11" onkeyup="suivant(this,'partPays',11,'accScreen')"
                                 styleClass="inscCB_SaisieTexte" />
</logic:iterate>
```

The console error :

> weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP
>   /jsp/Contents/bankAccountsContent.jsp bankAccountsContent.jsp:171:81:
>   This attribute is not recognized.
>                             " size="18"
>   maxlength="11".

with **accountsScreen** underlined

I've also tried another way in my jsp :

```
<html:text name="accScreen" property="accountsScreen[${index}].bic" size="18" maxlength="11"
                                 onkeyup="suivant(this,'partPays',11,'accScreen')"
                                 styleClass="inscCB_SaisieTexte" />
```

This time the console error was :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid indexed property
>   'accountsScreen[${index}]'

Do you have a solution to one of these problems or another way to do this?

Comment: Try with single quotes -  `property='<%="accountsScreen["+index+"].bic"%>'`.

Comment: It doesn't work better but it's not the same error : 'javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property accountsScreen[1].bic of bean accScreen'. accountsScreen is the server side name and bic has a getter following the standard rules. But accScreen is the jsp name (in struts logic iterate), maybe is it a lead.

Comment: It means that this syntax is correct and you need to fix names.

Comment: I've tried some variations but I can't find out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

Aleksandr M help me to find the lead to the final solution. Indeed I needed to use simple quotes instead of double ones. Then there was an access problem to the accountsScreen property because it wasn't and indexed one. Finally I needed 2 different names for getter, even if the arguments wasn't the same. So I add the indexed prefix to the indexed getter.

In the jsp :

```
<html:text name="BankAccountsActionForm" property='<%="indexedAccountsScreen["+index+ "].partAccountNumber2"%>'
```

in the java form, I needed an indexed property to access to an element of accountsScreen ArrayList. So I had the getter to access to an element by Index :

```
public void setAccountsScreen(int index, AccountScreenBean accScreen) {
    this.accountsScreen.add(index, accScreen);
}
public AccountScreenBean getIndexedAccountsScreen(int index) {
    return accountsScreen.get(index);
}
```

Thanks every one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your first "workaround" is the `<% %>` magic, because of the quotes. And it also seems unnecessary, as you should already have the indexed element in `accScreen`.
I would try

```
<logic:iterate name="BankAccountsActionForm" property="accountsScreen" id="accScreen" indexId="index">
    <html:text name="accScreen" property="bic" etc="..." />
</logic:iterate>
```

instead.

Comment: Actually it was my first shot. There isn't any console error but the input value isn't set. But I think it works in later version of struts, let's say 1.2 at least.

Comment: Strange. Is this the case when it doesn't even call the getter or is it another one?